# how to draw a multiple colors circle?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, android-glide

I want to draw multiple colors circle around the photo and this is obtained from me with this code:

[image: colors circle]

```
public class DrawPartCircleView extends View {

    private String mColor = "#000000";
    private float mRadius;
    private float mStrokeWidth = 14;
    private Map<String, Integer> mColorsMap;

    public DrawPartCircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawPartCircleView(Context context,  float radius, float strokeWidth, Map<String, Integer> colorsMap) {
        super(context);
        mRadius = radius;
        mStrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        mColorsMap = colorsMap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float width = (float) getWidth();
        float height = (float) getHeight();

        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(width / 2,
                height / 2, mRadius,
                Path.Direction.CW);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float center_x, center_y;
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        center_x = width / 2;
        center_y = height / 2;


        oval.set(center_x - mRadius,
                center_y - mRadius,
                center_x + mRadius,
                center_y + mRadius);

        int countColors = countColors(mColorsMap);
        int startDegree = 0;

        for (String key : mColorsMap.keySet()) {
            int stepDegree = (mColorsMap.get(key) * 360 / countColors);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(key));
            canvas.drawArc(oval, startDegree, stepDegree, false, paint);
            startDegree += stepDegree;
        }
    }

    private int countColors(Map<String, Integer> myColorsMap) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String key : myColorsMap.keySet()) {
            count += myColorsMap.get(key);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I have such a list view (more than 20 pieces). There are delays, jerks in the recycler view with this items.

[I looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315005/how-to-represent-circle-border-with-multiple-colors-in-android) but in this solution the problems arose when the elemets were on the list more than 10 pieces.

How do I draw a circle but also do not get worse in performance?
Perhaps I can do it with a [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?

Comment: you can draw an ark. So draw your circle arc by arc

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking performance, there are a couple of things that are sticking out.

1) You're making allocations within `onDraw()`.  `onDraw()` is called A LOT.  You should construct your `Path`, `Paint`, and `RectF` outside of `onDraw()`, and reuse them on subsequent calls to `onDraw()`.  Also, parse your colors into your color map ahead of time, so you don't have to parse them within `onDraw()`.

2)  Why does `countColors()` not just use `myColorsMap.keySet().size()`

Comment: myColorsMap.keySet().size() - not suitable for me, with this method I get a different result. I do not quite understand how I can achieve my goal with `Path`, `Paint`, and `RectF` for this reason I wrote it here.