# How to add dyanmic circular borders to imageview like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-imageview, whatsapp

Please guide me to add dynamic dotted border to image view like whatsapp doing in status screen, Kindly see the below image, I circled the functionality of that I want to achieve,

Whatsapp Status Screen

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316354/how-to-make-text-view-shape-circle-and-set-different-background-color-based-on-c/24778585

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315005/how-to-represent-circle-border-with-multiple-colors-in-android/53231638#53231638

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CircularImageView](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView). You can dynamically change borders. Maybe you'il have to make some arrangements. You can look at [example project](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView/tree/master/circularimageview-example).

Example.

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#8BC34A"/>
```

Comment: I want dotted dynamic border, please see the question properly.

Comment: Maybe you can add a progress component to a CircularImageView.  ex :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315005/how-to-represent-circle-border-with-multiple-colors-in-android